# Reset Password Using Django

Tags: python, django, reset-password

I am trying to reset password using Django but I am getting the following error:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /reset/done/
Method Not Allowed: /reset/done/
```

Below are my forms:

**Form Which Sent Link To My Email**

```
<form action="{% url 'reset_pass' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

**Form Which I Get On Clicking That Link**

```
<form action="{% url 'password_reset_complete' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_pass" placeholder="New Password" required autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_pass" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Password" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

**URL**

```
path('reset/pass/', views.reset_pass, name='reset_pass'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="feebeeapp/reset_form.html"), name='password_reset_form'),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='feebeeapp/login.html'), name='password_reset_complete')
```

Not sure, what I am doing wrong. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You are submitting to the wrong view. You should submit to a `PasswordResetConfirmView` view, that will send the email.

Comment: On PasswordResetConfirmView, I get the form which code I have shown above. After that, I believe so that I will have to do PasswordResetCompleteView.

Comment: no, it is a very common pattern to submit to the *same* view, but then with a POST request. The view will email a reset link, and then make a *redirect* to the `password_reset_complete` view. The `PasswordResetConfirmView` thus both handles GET requests (to render the form), and POST requests (to send the reset link).

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting to the wrong view. You are supposed to make a POST request to a `PasswordResetConfirmView` view.

If your `PasswordResetConfirmView` is thus registered as:

```
path('reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset')
```

then in your form you work with:

```
<form action="{% url 'password_reset' %}" method="post">
    …
</form>
```

Normally you already use this view to *render* the form. So you submit a *POST* request to the *same* view.

This view will send an *email* with a *reset link*, and then will redirect to the `password_reset_complete` view.

Comment: The reset link redirected me to this form. After which I do PasswordResetCompleteView but got this error. I also tried PasswordResetConfirmView but I got the Assertion error.

Comment: It does redirect but it's not updating password. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @MaisumAbbas: but the update of the password is never done when you *reset* your password. That is done through the email link. If you want to update your form, you work with a **`PasswordChangeView`**...

Comment: @MaisumAbbas: a **`PasswordResetView`** is used when you *forgot* your password, and thus a reset link is emailed to update that password.

Comment: I have updated my code. Please see that. @WillamVanOnsem

Comment: @MaisumAbbas: if you change the password, then this will also not send any reset link. The idea of a reset link is that the user forgot his password, but still has access to something that is password protected like his mailbox. A `PasswordChangeView` on the other hand asks the current password, and will update it, so in that case the user *knows* the current password.